# Why can't I use this.getApplication() in an onClick() in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to check if a session ID is set in my main activity class before I execute a chunk of code. I have a class SessionID to store the id if there is one. I was trying to access it in `an onClick()` by using the following:

`if ( ((SessionID) this.getApplication()).getSessionID() != null ) {}`

However, it gives the error "Cannot resolve method 'getApplication()' "

This line works almost anywhere else in my main activity. I tried looking up the details of how activities work but I didn't find anything related to this.

Question: What's different about `onClick()` that I can't call `this.Application()` ?

Here is the onClick() I'm using

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            // Calls downloadPDF to download PDF in background thread

            if ( ((SessionID) this.getApplication()).getSessionID() != null) {

                new downloadPDF().execute("http://10.0.2.2/DBConnector/public_html/mobilePDFNew.php");
            }
```

Comment: put all your code here please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using an `onClickListener`, you're creating an instance of an inner class. The scope of `this` changes here, and no longer refers to your activity / fragment context.

Assuming you're in an activity, use `MyActivity.this` instead.

Comment: what if onClick is not an (anonymous) inner class ?

Comment: It's highly likely it is. `View.OnClickListener` has the definition for `onClick`, and I suspect that this is what the asker is using in his code

Answer (score 1):

`getApplication()` is a method of the `Activity` class. So if you have a code like this in your `Activity`:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
         if ( ((SessionID) this.getApplication()).getSessionID() != null ) {}
    }
})
```

in this case `this` refers to an instance of OnClickListener. Instead you should use `%ActivityName%.this.getApplication()`